# I have to click twice to activate any button action (Ionic/Angular)

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an app which is an `Ionic` Project.

in android it is working fine. But when I build and run the project in `ios` I have to click Every button `twice` (double tap) in `Simulator` and in `Device` also.

I don't know what exactly is the issue. and how to debug.

Is their someone who knows what to do ?

**Edit** this is happening for Buttons and `a` tag.

I put this CSS:

```
  .button:hover
   {background-color:red;}
```

and when I run my project and click on button then this `:hover` css is applied and `click` event not triggers.

Comment: Which version of Ionic are you on?

Comment: @AdityaSingh ionic version `1.7.12`

Answer (score 2):

On iOS devices, I believe the first touch is seen as 'hovering' in a similar way to when you hover over something with your mouse. Essentially, the first touch on iOS is seen as hover and the second is seen as a real click.

You can listen for `.hover` events instead of `.click` events based on the browser, which will be Safari on iOS and Chrome on Android. Although some iOS devices may be running chrome, this could work for the majority of the cases, assuming it is possible with Ionic.

Comment: what can I do to fix this @jaredash

Comment: Never worked with Ionic before, but based on my knowledge of javascript you are probably able to listen for .hover events instead of .click events based on the browser, which will be Safari on iOS and Chrome on Android. Although some iOS devices may be running chrome, this could work for the majority of the cases, assuming it is possible with Ionic