# Mobile triggering two 'click' events

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm working on a rather large web application and some of my click handlers are registering two clicks on mobile devices. Note that these are both `click` events, not a case of `click` and `touchstart`....

```
$("#myDiv").on('click', function(e){
    console.log(e); // logs two click events despite code below

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    return false;
});
```

I cannot isolate and reproduce the problem in a sandbox or fiddle which means there is likely a problem somewhere else in my code.

However, I have managed a workaround because I noticed that in one of the two events fired the *view* property is null:

```
event(1){
   altKey:false,
   bubbles:true,
   button:0,
   ...
   ...
   type: "click",
   view: null,          //  <------this is null for some reason
   ...
}

event(2){
   altKey:false,
   bubbles:true,
   button:0,
   ...
   ...
   type: "click",
   view: Window,
   ...
}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this second click event and why the *view* property is null in the first event?

Comment: Are you using a gestures library?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794181/jquery-mobile-tap-event-triggered-for-twice

Comment: No gesture libraries, and both of these events are `click` events, there is no 'tap`

Comment: Where in the code are you adding the click event? Is it in the jqm pageshow or pagecreate?

Comment: @ezanker neither, this particular handler is bound in the `done` callback of an ajax call, after the fetched html is appended to the page...

Answer (score 0):

most probably you are testing on iOS device. 
In ios Device first touch is treated as `hover` event and second is treated as `touch` that's why you are getting this behaviour.
 I am also suffering from this.
 What i did to solve this removed all hover css and written this jquery.

```
       <script>$('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
                      var el = $(this);
                      var link = el.attr('href');
                      window.location = link;
                      });</script>
    <script>$('button').on('click touchend', function(e) {
                      var el = $(this);
                      var link = el.attr('href');
                      window.location = link;
                      });</script>
```

I don't think this is best solution but it works. Only I have to work without hover.

Please let me know if you find any other solution of it.Here is myquestion link:

[MyQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240278/i-have-to-click-twice-to-activate-any-button-action-ionic-angular)

Comment: If this issue were caused by `touch` events wouldn't the `event.type` reflect this?